# flutter NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'logo'

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

am new in flutter an i have a problem with my flutter code
the problem is

NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'logo' Receiver: "{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}"

my code is

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> LoadData() async {
  final name = await Hive.box<dynamic>('my_db');
  final result = name.values.toList();
  print(result);
  //print result is gotten perfectly from hive box
  return name.values.toList();
}

SizedBox(
  height: 500,
  child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: LoadData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('loading'),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data[1].logo.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.more_horiz,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }),
);
```

Comment: Have stored list of  object(model class) on `my_db`?

Comment: are you using adapter class?

Comment: I don't have idea about adapter class am new to flutter that is all my code in questions above

Comment: ok, what do you get by printing `result`, About [adapter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/type_adapters)

Comment: I got this in print results 

            `[{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}, {id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}, {id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}]`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are recieving means that the `snapshot.data[1]` is a string not the object you are expecting to contain a logo.

Comment: Not a good answer am likely to get logo by index.    snapshot.data.logo

Comment: This is the result from my hive box `(my_db)` 

`[{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}, {id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}, {id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}]`

Am expecting to go get logo as text by each index

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access a property logo on a String object.

The string you are trying to access is `"{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}"` which seems to be a string representation of a Map object. Parse this string to a Map object before trying to access its properties. Your listview should mirror the below:

```
import 'dart:convert';

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final itemData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data[index]);
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(
                itemData['logo'].toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

In the above, we decode the string to a Map.

A better way to handle would be to map the json to a custom class.

```
class Provider {
  Provider({
    required this.id,
    required this.network,
    required this.discount,
    required this.logo,
  });
  final String id;
  final String network;
  final int discount;
  final String logo;

  factory Provider.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final id = data['id'] as String;
    final network = data['network'] as String;
    final discount = int.parse(data['discount']);
    final logo = data['logo'] as String;
    return Provider(
      id: id,
      network: network,
      discount: discount,
      logo: logo,
    );
  }
}
```

Your listview would look like the below:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Decoding the string to Map
    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data[index]);
    
    // Mapping the Map to Provider object
    final itemData = Provider.fromJson(decodedData);
    
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(
                itemData.logo, // Accessing logo from Provider object
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: The second pattern is advised over the first

Comment: I tired your code sadly there's error in this line of code `'"$1":'` @Codefarmer

Comment: Corrected the code @Eniedi Monday.

Comment: You should adopt the second pattern though. its more or less similar to @msutanto solution.

Comment: i tried the second pattern but  didn't work for me error is `Unexpected character (at character 2)
{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}
 ^` @codefarmer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your error message, the snapshot.data return a String object

**"{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}"**

with quotation mark at the beginning and end.

A String does not has the logo field you were trying to access. Instead you need to:

First, turn it into a JSON object, by parsing the String, using *jsonDecode*

```
Import 'dart:convert'; 
  
final jsonObj = jsonDecode(snapshot.data());
```

Now you have two choices:
**Directly accessing the logo from the jsonObj**

```
final logo = jsonObj['logo']
```

Or, the longer but type-safe way, by **creating a class**, e.g. named Merchant, specifying the field names and fromJson factory method

```
class Merchant {
          Merchant({required this.id, required this.network, required this.discount, required this.logo});
          final String id;
          final String network;
          final int discount;
          final String logo;
    
    factory Merchant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
        final id = data['id'] as String;
        final network = data['network'] as String;
        final discount = int.parse(data['discount'])
        final logo = data['logo'] as String;
        return Merchant(id: id, network: network, discount: discount, logo: logo);
      }
}
```

*ADDITIONAL NOTE:* paste the code above into a .dart file, name it merchant.dart (or sth). For the ease of scalability, I would suggest to store the merchant.dart file in a model folder, under lib folder **lib>model>merchant.dart**

Finally, map the **JSON object into the Merchant class to create an instance of Merchant**

```
final Merchant merchant = Merchant.fromJson(jsonObj);
```

*You need to import the merchant.dart file in order to access the Merchant class and fromJson method.*

Now you can safely access the logo field

```
final String logo = merchant.logo;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your second `code` with class look pretty but I don't have idea of putting the class  together in my code to achieve my results am new in flutter

Comment: I will accept your answer if it been added to my exiting code thank you

Comment: For a neat and scalable architecture, you can create a model folder under the lib folder. Inside this model folder, create a dart file, let's name it merchant.dart, containing the second code as above. You can import this merchant.dart file anywhere you need to reference Merchant class. PS: as you need to create more classes - hence .dart files in the future, you can store the files in this model folder.